# Receiving different gain values on two RX channels on Ettus USRP B210

Tags: software-defined-radio, usrp

I am transmitting a continuous wave and using one USRP B210 with the kitchen_sink tool in order to save the received samples from two RX channels (v.3.15.0)

When I look into the received signal on both channels, it seems that the Gain factor is only being applied to one of the channels as shown below.

[image: Blue line is from channel 0 and orange line is from channel 1]

This is the command that I am sending when executing kitchen_sink:

> ./kitchen_sink --rx-freq=868000000 --rx-gain=76 --rate=1e6
>   --rx-channels=0,1 --rx-ant=TX/RX --rx-file=data/_%1%_usrp.dat --clock=external --time=external --rx-start-delay=3 --rx-freq-delay=0.5

My UHD version is 3.15.0

What could be causing the difference in the signal between the two channels?

Comment: 1. Kitchen sink is a debugging tool, not a productive program. Don't use it for such purposes.$$ $$
 2. This sounds like an issue for the usrp-users mailing list, or support@ettus.com, but not for ham.stackexchange.com, to be honest.$$ $$
 3. try using `rx_samples_to_file` or GNU Radio instead. $$ $$

Comment: Thank you for your comments @MarcusMüller.  
$$  $$
1. I understand that. However, I faced the same issue when I wrote my own code to receive the data.
$$  $$
2. Good idea, I might try there.
$$  $$
3. I was using `rx_samples_to_file` when I was receiving just from one channel. From what I could gather, there is no way to receive from both channels using this tool. I am not sure if the GNU Radio could help with I am trying to achieve, but I will confirm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference was caused by the splitter I was using to send the signal to both channels.

Comment: I'm glad that you found the problem Bruno!